# Scatter plot from two lists with BarLegend

Tags: plotting, legending

I have two lists

```
listx = {};
Do[x = RandomReal[{0, 1}]; AppendTo[listx, x], {1000}];
listy = {};
Do[y = RandomReal[{0, 10}]; AppendTo[listy, y], {1000}];
```

I can make a scatter plot as

```
data = Transpose@{listx, listy};
plotxy = ListPlot[data]
```

But in this scater plot, I want to add [`BarLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html) in such a way that the point `(0.5,5)` has the darkest color and as the points start to deviate from this point the color gets lighter and lighter.

Comment: Not an answer but you can generate 1000 random numbers, simply by: `listx = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 1000];` and `listy = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 1000];`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
data3 = Style[{##}, 
     ColorData["Rainbow"][Abs[(#1 - 0.5)] + Abs[1/10 (#2 - 5)]]] & @@@
    data;
Legended[ListPlot[data3, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01]], 
 BarLegend["Rainbow"]]
```

[image]

**Update for your question in the comment:**

The color function `ColorData["Rainbow"]` ranges from `0` to `1` so the value has to be used within this range. `Abs` function basically works as a Ramp function in the two directions and centered at the center of the plot.

```
Row[{Plot3D[Abs[(x - 0.5)] + Abs[1/10 (y - 5)],{x,0,1},{y,0,10}],ContourPlot[Abs[(x - 0.5)] + Abs[1/10 (y - 5)], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 10},
          ContourLabels -> (Text[Style[#3, Bold, 14, Red], {#1, #2}] &), 
         ContourShading -> None]}]
```

[image]

You can see in this plot that `Abs[(#1 - 0.5)] + Abs[1/10 (#2 - 5)]` is within `0` and `1` for the range of the plot and it drops in the four directions. So when you apply `ColorData["Rainbow"]` for the values resulted from `Abs[(#1 - 0.5)] + Abs[1/10 (#2 - 5)]` you will get the color gradient that you want.

[image]

Comment: Another option may be to use `GrayLevel` instead of `ColorData["Rainbow"]`, to generate a gradient from black (closest) to white (furthest away). (+1)

Comment: @Algohi, nice answer, thanks a lot. could you please explain this part of the code "Abs[(#1 - 0.5)] + Abs[1/10 (#2 - 5)]". i am confused because for the actual code, the lists do not obey such simple structure that i can easily rescale by 1/10. how to rescale lists for example:
listx= {min(x), ...,x0,.., max(x) }
listy= {min(y), ...,y0,.., max(y) }
here, {x0,y0} is the point with the darkest point and other points as go away from it gets lighter.

Comment: @SAS see the update

Comment: @ Algohi, excellent !!! but i need to mention one thing, for the example we are considering, Abs[(x - x0)/maxx] + Abs[(y - y0)/maxy does work approximately, but it should be properly normalized for general purpose to work and the correct formula should be Abs[(x - x0)/maxx]/Sqrt@2 + Abs[(y - y0)/maxy]/Sqrt@2 , which works for any combination. you may edit it.

thank you again, such a nice answer :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
data = Transpose[{RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10000], 
    RandomReal[{0, 10}, 10000]}];
Legended[Graphics[{Function[{x, 
      y}, {ColorData["Rainbow"][
       Norm[{x, y/10} - {0.5, 0.5}]/Sqrt[0.5]], Point[{x, y}]}] @@@ 
    data, {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[{0.5, 5}]}}, 
  AspectRatio -> Full, Frame -> True], BarLegend["Rainbow"]]
```

[image]